# Web api controller with multiple post methods with the same name but with different parameters

Tags: http-post, asp.net-web-api

I have web api controller that has multiple post methods with the same name but with different parameters; when i run the application, i got an error:-
**Multiple actions were found that match the request**
note:- **I don't want to use Action Routing as i want to unify my clients who use my web api**

```
public Customer Post(Customer customer)
{

}

public Product Post(Product product)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there's no way to distinguish between those two Post methods based on the URL that's getting passed to the web api.

The way to handle this would be to use a separate controller. One controller would be "api/Customer" and would have Post method that takes a Customer:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    public Customer Post(Customer customer) { }
}
```

The other would be "api/Product" and take a Product:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public Product Post(Product product) { }
}
```

If you really really wanted to pass both into one controller, you could create a class that has all the properties of both Customer and Product, and then look at the properties to figure out what just got passed into your controller. But... yuck.

```
public class EvilController : ApiController
{
    public ProductOrCustomer Post(ProductOrCustomer whoKnows)
    {
        // Do stuff to figure out if whoKnows has
        // Product properties or Customer properties
    }
}
```

Comment: No these solutions are not applicable as it will increase the complexity of my apis

Comment: @Bill's solution should be the right answer if you want to build restful web services. Each controller would be responsible for one resource (Product or Customer). It can't be both. If you want to keep both in the same Controller, then you need to specify a RouteAttribute and achieve the same result you would have achieved with two controllers, but less organised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single controller,  with a single method taking a parameter of an interface type that both classes implement.  Then call private handlers based on runtime type.

Comment: I wonder how the return type will be. At least as long the op must return a .net object and not enough with i.e. a jsonresult.

Comment: How to achieve this solution?